# Set initial model value if model is an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I set the default value of a model if it is part of an array?

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      value: 1,
      values: [],
      products: [{
        name: 'test 1',
      },
      {
        name: 'test 2',
      }]
    }
  },
  created() {
    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      this.values.push(1);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url(https://unpkg.com/vue-range-component@1.0.2/dist/vue-range-slider.min.css);

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.app-content {
  padding:40px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-range-component@1.0.2/dist/vue-range-slider.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="app-content">
    <div v-for="(product, index) in products">
      <p>
        {{ product.name }}: {{ values[index] }}
      </p>
      <vue-range-slider v-model="values[index]" min="0" max="10"></vue-range-slider>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>example of working if not an array:</div>
  <p>
    this works: {{ value }}
  </p>
  <vue-range-slider v-model="value" min="0" max="10"></vue-range-slider>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above example, the array sliders don't show the number after the colon until after you start sliding, where as if you set the default value in the `data` (as in the single value) then it works fine

So my question is how do you bind a default value to the model when it is an array of unknown size (the products are loaded from an api so there won't always be 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for (i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    this.values.push(1);
}
```

Comment: In have that in my `created` method?

Comment: Yes you forgive "this" before "products.length"

Comment: hahaha, damn! that seems to have fixed it.  Thanks